# Conditional bracketing in macro

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am trying to make a macro for typesetting higher-categories, and would like to automatically enclose the optional argument in brackets if it is an expression containing + or -.

In particular I would like to have something like `\cat[<optional_rank>]{<name>}`, so that for example `\cat{Bord}`, `\cat[n]{Fus}`, and `\cat[2]{Rep}` typeset **Bord**, *n***Fus**, and 2**Rep** respectively, but `\cat[n+1]{Fus}` and `\cat[n-k-2]{Rep}` typeset (*n+1*)**Fus** and (*n-k-2*)**Rep** respectively.

How can I achieve the automatic bracketing? I am almost sure that the answer will involve `xparse`, but I don't know how to do it myself.

For convenience here is a MWE (that does not do exactly what I want yet)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\cat}[2][]{{#1}\mathbf{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \(\cat{Bord}\), \(\cat[n]{Fus}\), \(\cat[2]{Rep}\), \(\cat[n+1]{Fus}\), \(\cat[n-k-2]{Rep}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need something a bit more lower level than `xparse`, can we just look for `+` and `-`? Then some `expl3` string match might be enough (see also the `xstring` package)

Comment: I have `xparse` loaded anyway (since I always load the package `physics` which requires `xparse`). I don't know how what `expl3` does, but I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Note in general that the `physics` package is not well recommended due to many poor design choices.

Comment: yep, I know. I have been following the related questions for alternatives here, but until something better comes up I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This checks if `+` or `-` is in the argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cat}{om}
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}{ \is_cat_prefix:n { #1 } }
  \mathbf{#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \is_cat_prefix:n
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { + }
   { (#1) } % there is +
   {
    \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { - }
     { (#1) } % there is -
     { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\(\cat{Bord}\), \(\cat[n]{Fus}\), \(\cat[2]{Rep}\), \(\cat[n+1]{Fus}\), \(\cat[n-k-2]{Rep}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use `listofitems` here to check for the literal presence of `+` or `-` in argument `#1` (others can be added).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand{\cat}[2][\relax]{%
  \setsepchar{+||-}%
  \readlist\checksgns{#1}%
  \ifnum\listlen\checksgns[]>1\relax(#1)\else#1\fi\mathbf{#2}}
\begin{document}
    \(\cat{Bord}\), \(\cat[n]{Fus}\), \(\cat[2]{Rep}\), \(\cat[n+1]{Fus}\), \(\cat[n-k-2]{Rep}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]