# Conditional delimiting parentheses in macro of "function evaluation"

Tags: macros, conditionals, delimiters

I defined the following macro:

```
\newcommand\evalf[3]{\left.#1\right\vert_{#2}^{#3}}
```

It simply types the "evaluation bar" when computing integrals (*inter alia*). Now, typesetting `\evalf{\frac{x^4}{4}}{0}{1}` is all very well, but I would like to conditionally add parentheses `\left(#1\right)` for something like `\exp(x) - \frac{x^2}{3}`; that is, for functions with "more than one term", so to speak.

I saw [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564005/conditional-bracketing-in-macro), but here the condition is the mere presence of `+` or `-`, which would put parentheses around something like `(x+1)^2`, and I want to avoid unnecessary delimiters.

I rummaged through the doc. of `xstring` but couldn't find anything useful for this. Is this even possible? Can LaTeX "distinguish monomials"?

Thanks!

Comment: If there's no programmatic way of achieve this result in an automated way, then surely it is better to use human judgement to place these parentheses on an as-needed basis, otherwise you'll always find edge cases where you need to override them. For example, `\frac{a - b}{c}` should be handled like a single term, but `\frac{a}{c} - \frac{b}{c}` be handled as two terms. Ultimately, how much would have to be put in to derive an automated `\evalf` and how many times will you use it?

Comment: I am writing a Calculus 1 textbook, so I'd use it quite a lot; also, I typeset notes for my students, and I teach other Calculus subjects. It is quite right to say it is better to use human judgement, but nowhere does it say that a question has to be "pragmatic"; if so, I'll get scolded and lose reputation for wasting people's time. I think it is an interesting problem, though.

Comment: [systeme](https://ctan.org/pkg/systeme?lang=en) is able to detect monomials. This does not allow you to solve your problem, but indicates that it is in principle possible. Other alternatives include that you add a macro that switches locally to the "with parentheses" mode.